# Laravel orwhere and whereBetween query not working together

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5.4

I have a situation to filter user from database in a way that to filter from two columns of the table with a particular id and that should be filtered with a range of date.

My code is as shown below.

```
$fetchSelectedUser=Wallet_Transaction::select('wallet__transactions.from as FromUser','wallet__transactions.type','wallet__transactions.date','wallet__transactions.amount','wallet__transactions.balance_after',
               'wallet__transactions.type','wallet__transactions.description','wallet__transactions.to as ToUser','users.name as FromName',DB::raw('(select name from users where users.id = ToUser) as toName'))
               ->join('users','users.id','=','wallet__transactions.from')
               ->where('wallet__transactions.from','=',$user_id)->orWhere('wallet__transactions.to','=',$user_id)
               ->whereBetween('wallet__transactions.db_date',[$fromDate,$toDate])->get();
```

what I have tried is put a static date, and is not working. Also I removed `orWhere` and `whereBetween` independently. That is working. But it will not working together.

Comment: could you explain what you want to achieve here, your query with some example??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `where()` closure to group your `conditional` query:

```
$fetchSelectedUser=Wallet_Transaction::select('wallet__transactions.from as FromUser','wallet__transactions.type','wallet__transactions.date','wallet__transactions.amount','wallet__transactions.balance_after',
           'wallet__transactions.type','wallet__transactions.description','wallet__transactions.to as ToUser','users.name as FromName',DB::raw('(select name from users where users.id = ToUser) as toName'))
           ->join('users','users.id','=','wallet__transactions.from')
           ->where(function($q) use ($user_id){
                $q->where('wallet__transactions.from','=',$user_id)->orWhere('wallet__transactions.to','=',$user_id);
           })->whereBetween('wallet__transactions.db_date',[$fromDate,$toDate])->get();
```

Comment: how to pass userid to this